# CSS code changes when used PHP

Tags: php, css

I have this HTML/CSS here:

```
<div class="liste">
    <div class="content">
        <h4>Cyekl something</h4>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores, ullam, consectetur, totam vel consequuntur
            quas sunt nulla rerum maxime saepe repudiandae voluptate porro laudantium repellat rem non doloremque? Ea,
            delectus, quis quod nemo deleniti velit 
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="listeimage">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/116/80/" alt="">
    </div>
    <p class="pris">Pris 9.995 kr.</p>
    <a href="#">
        <h4 class="mereinfo">Mere info</h4>
    </a>
</div>
```

and when I'm using it with PHP, the sidebar I have on my page moves into the content class and just kinda ruins everything.

```
    $cykel_id = $row['cykel_id'];
    $cykel_tekst = $row['cykel_tekst'];
    $cykel_pris = $row['cykel_pris'];
    $img = 'http://lorempixel.com/116/80/';
    echo '<div class="liste"><div class="content"><h4>'.$cykel_id.'</h4>'.'<p>'.$cykel_tekst.'</p>'.'</div><div class="listeimage"><img src="'.$img.'"</div><p class="pris">'.$cyke_pris.'</p>'.'<a href="#"><h4 class="mereinfo">Mere info</h4></a></div>';
}
```

And thats my php code I have no idea what's going wrong hope someone can help me.

Comment: It seems you are missing your iterator when showing us the code, I assume this was a mistake?

Comment: Hejså! Well, what is the actual HTML output from your PHP script? Does it differ from your sample HTML? I'm suspecting an unclosed element somewhere.

Comment: Minor detail, you have $cyke_pris instead of $cykel_pris on your echo line.

Comment: Thanks to you all, somehow there was apparently more mistakes in my code then i thought and you all seem to be right so thanks to all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indent your code properly and you will see the mistakes much faster.

After formatting, your PHP `echo` looks like this:

```
echo '
    <div class="liste">
        <div class="content">
            <h4>'.$cykel_id.'</h4>
            '.'<p>'.$cykel_tekst.'</p>'.'
        </div>
        <div class="listeimage">
            <img src="'.$img.'"
        </div>
        <p class="pris">'.$cyke_pris.'</p>
        '.'
        <a href="#">
            <h4 class="mereinfo">Mere info</h4>
        </a>
    </div>
';
```

The `<img />` tag is not closed properly.
Also, there are some unnecessary `'.'` fragments here and there, but they are not affecting the correctness.

The line with `img` tag should look like:

```
<img src="'.$img.'" />
```

(and to be fully valid, it should have `alt` attribute, too)

Comment: Wow i feel so stupid, Thank you very much, i just somehow always end up confusing myself, when i have to put php code into my HTML like this But thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't close your `img` tag. Also, you had a typo at `$cyke_pris`. It should be `$cykel_pris`. The following format may help you avoid this error in the future:

```
<?php
$cykel_tekst = $row['cykel_tekst'];
$cykel_pris = $row['cykel_pris'];
$img = 'http://lorempixel.com/116/80/';
echo "<div class='liste'>
        <div class='content'>
          <h4>$cykel_id</h4>
          <p>$cykel_tekst</p>
        </div>
        <div class='listeimage'>
          <img src='$img' />
        </div>
        <p class='pris'>$cykel_pris</p>
        <a href='#'><h4 class='mereinfo'>Mere info</h4></a>
      </div>";
?>
```

You can use output buffering to get rid of tho white spaces, or just take them out yourself.